# Camera calibration and distortion parameters data archive (for OpenCV)?

Tags: images

I wonder if there is a library of [Camera calibration and distortion parameters](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) (as presented in OpenCV camera model or convertable to it) that would cover main cell phone models (iOS\Android) and popular web cameras?

It shall include main distortion parameters such as `k1, k2, p1, p2, k3` or a formula on how to convert into them.

As For now I found [this](https://github.com/htw-inka/cam-intrinsics-db/tree/master/database) and [this](https://github.com/BloodAxe/Camera-intrinsics-database/tree/master/Devices):

```
ipad2-front    3.3398628913791757e-02 3.6208493485118960e-02
    -1.3077939973028386e-03 -2.0534401775609144e-03
    -7.7594364452126163e-01


ipad3-rear 2.3628479801842187e-01 -1.4838185680077374e+00
    6.1164837177226554e-03 -1.3917464527942961e-02
    2.3228740041746385e+00

ipad3-front 2.8173092926263271e-02 -7.7958809141800769e-02
    -3.8787165863786166e-03 2.2533495554116770e-02
    8.5297577164938476e-01

macbook-pro-2009   -1.0939089498246352e-01 5.1756087136315387e-01
    1.8180735389345232e-03 -3.3265554687567211e-03
    -7.2079094436631030e-01
```